# Opening a vue page through external URL with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Laravel in combination with Vue. I have a path to the main web application named '/app/main'. This loads a specific vue component 'main.vue'.

A functionality of the page is that an email with a summary with information gets sent to a customer. I want this email to have a link to the page, but with a specific ID for this order.

So a link like http://nameofdomain/app/main/100000 should open the default page http://nameofdomain/app/main, where I would catch the 100000 somewhere as a passed parameter, so that I can handle showing that specific ID.

At first I thought I had to adjust the laravel pathing and use dynamic parameters, but this seems wrong, as I ignore the whole vue part, which is my landing page. Then I looked into something similar for Vue, where you add a dynamic parameter like:

> path: '/app/main/:id',

But this does not work. It doesn't see http://nameofdomain/app/main/100000 as a valid page (404 error).

So how can I provide my customers with a link containing an ID, so that when they follow the link, they are redirected to my Laravel/Vue page and it only shows the ID for that order (by passing it in the URL)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your client side separated from you server side?

If not, can you please provide your Laravel route definition for that Vue component? maybe you just need to add that param matching in your Server side code too

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.